# HATEOAS header as a string

Tags: php, rest, yii, yii2, hateoas

I am building a RESTful API with Yii2 but have some questions in regards to HATEOAS support. Requests will output the pagination headers and include the HATEOAS header.

However the HATEOAS header contains all links as one long string. This is not very helpful for the consumer. Is this standard? Is there a way to change the format in Yii into something that is easier to handle?

[image: HATEOAS Header]

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's standard, GitHub uses the same format. Are you getting your results in XML?

Comment: No, the response body is JSON.

Answer (score 2):

Does the following look good?

```
"_links": {
    "self": {
        "href": "http://localhost/users?page=1"
    },
    "next": {
        "href": "http://localhost/users?page=2"
    },
    "last": {
        "href": "http://localhost/users?page=50"
    }
}
```

If so, you can easily have links like that. Make sure your data model implements `Linkable` interface and then implement `getLinks()` method:

```
class User extends ActiveRecord implements Linkable
{
    public function getLinks()
    {
        return [
            Link::REL_SELF => Url::to(['user/view', 'id' => $this->id], true),
        ];
    }
}
```

`Serializer` will automatically add `"_links"` to your response.

More info [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-resources.html#links).

Answer (score 0):

Multiple HTTP headers with the same name can be combined by comma-separating them.

The easiest way to get access to each individual link is to use a HTTP Link header parser library, any of which will for sure already have support multiple comma-separated header values.

It's very important that any client that consumes this supports both a HTTP Header appearing multiple times, and the comma-separated syntax because an intermediate (like a proxy, load balancer, CDN) might change the many-header to combined-header syntax. A good client supports both.